# controller declaration in mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc

How can we make controller classes without suffixing "**Controller**" in the class name?

Comment: This is part of MVC's Convention Over Configuration philosophy.  You may be able to change this convention, but why would you want to?

Comment: Why would you want to defy the convention? It makes things much easier on other developers who have to maintain the code.

Comment: .net mvc is opensource technology, you can dowload sourses and rewrite all mvc source code to the way that you want

Comment: Are there any examples available for this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is convention by default and is implemented in [DefaultControllerFactory Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.defaultcontrollerfactory.aspx). You could create your own controller factory class that implements `IControllerFactory` and then use the code in `Global.asax` to make application use your controller factory

```
        protected void Application_Start()
        {
...
            ControllerBuilder.Current.SetControllerFactory(MyControllerFactory);
...
        }
```